# CodeIgniter 4 - How to display Flashdata inside a View?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm upgrading my project from CodeIgniter 3 to CodeIgniter 4,
I'm trying to display a flashdata message inside a view but unfortunately I get differents error for each method I try.

In CodeIgniter 3, I used to call something like:

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('message')) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I try the same in CodeIgniter 4 but I get this error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined property: CodeIgniter\View\View::$session
```

Can any one show me how to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it could be useful to you : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use session() function directly:

```
<?php if (session()->getFlashdata('message') !== NULL) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?php echo session()->getFlashdata('message'); ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The context ($this) is an instance of the View class --> you don't have access to the Session instance directly

You can create new instance below

```
$session = \Config\Services::session();
```

Comment: the you can get from $data = $session->flashdata("key")

Comment: and also please mark as answer if you solved, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In CodeIgniter 4 the new way to set Flash data `$session->setFlashdata('item', 'value');` and to view `$session->getFlashdata('item');`

You can check it out here : [Set  Flash data in session in CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=flashdata#flashdata)

Answer (score 1):

I just use another way to display a flashdata and it works fine.

In my controller, I added a new index to the data passed to the view:

```
$data['message'] = "Sorry, you must login first";
return view('login', $data);
```

Then in the view `login.php` I call it like this:

```
<?php if (isset($message)) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I just use the `markAsFlashdata()` method and It works perfectly. Here's what I did in the controller just before the `return` method:

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Sorry, you must login first';
$session = session();
$session->markAsFlashdata('error');
```

Then in the view I access the flashdata using `$_SESSION['error']`:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['error'])): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        <?= $_SESSION['error']; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line just after `echo $this->section('content');`

```
$session = \Config\Services::session(); 

<?php if (isset($message)) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now my solution has been to create a view method in BaseController.php.
The idea is to add more "common" info into the $data array.

```php
    /* In BaseController.php */

    /**
     * view function replaced 
     */
    public function view(string $name, array $data = [], array $options = []): string
    {
        // Inject global data        
        $data = array_merge($data,["controller" => $this]);        
        return view($name,$data,$options);
    }

    /**
     * Temporary message
     */
    public function flash($message, $type = 'info') {
        $this->session->setFlashdata('flash_message', 
            ["message" => $message, "type" => $type]);        
    }

    public function getFlash() {
        return $this->session->getFlashdata('flash_message');
    }

   /* In the descendant controller */
   return $this->view('products/list',['products' => $products]);

   /* In the view */
   <div id="messages">
      <?php if($flash = $controller->getFlash()) : ?>
          <?= view_cell('Base::alert', $flash); ?>
      <?php endif ?>
   </div>
```